# querySelectorAll with forEach function not working for toggle button on carousel slides

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created a template part in PHP that copies a button to each slide in a carousel using fullpage.js. The template part has a hidden div that should open up navigation for each slide. Trying the code below, I can only get this button to work on the first slide. I'm thinking an iterated class name might help, but not sure why querySelectorAll wouldn't do it. Any advice appreciated...

http://www.pulsecreative-clients.com/staging/hogshead/#golf

```js
    const clickOnMe = document.querySelectorAll(".course-button");

    let clickOnMe = document.querySelectorAll(".course-button"); 
    Array.from(clickOnMe).forEach(el => {
        el.addEventListener("click", e => { 
            let showBox = e.currentTarget.nextElementSibling;
            showBox.classList.toggle("open-nav"); 
        }); 
    });
```

```css
.subnav-content {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 15%;
    z-index: 1;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #000;
    display: none;
}

.golfcoursebutton {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    min-width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 4px;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000; 
    text-align: center;
}

.open-nav {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="jump-button" class="jumpbuttons-container">
    <div class="subnav">
        <button class="course-button">
            JUMP TO <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="subnav-content">
            <div style="display: flex;">
                <div class="golfcoursebutton"><a href="#golf/1">1</a></div>
                <div class="golfcoursebutton"><a href="#golf/2">2</a></div>
                <div class="golfcoursebutton"><a href="#golf/3">3</a></div>
                <div class="golfcoursebutton"><a href="#golf/4">4</a></div>
                <div class="golfcoursebutton"><a href="#golf/5">5</a></div>
                <div class="golfcoursebutton"><a href="#golf/6">6</a></div>
            </div>

            <div style="display: flex;">
                <div class="golfcoursebutton"><a href="#golf/7">7</a></div>
                <div class="golfcoursebutton"><a href="#golf/8">8</a></div>
                <div class="golfcoursebutton"><a href="#golf/9">9</a></div>
                <div class="golfcoursebutton"><a href="#golf/10">10</a></div>
                <div class="golfcoursebutton"><a href="#golf/11">11</a></div>
                <div class="golfcoursebutton"><a href="#golf/12">12</a></div>
            </div>

            <div style="display: flex;">
                <div class="golfcoursebutton"><a href="#golf/13">13</a></div>
                <div class="golfcoursebutton"><a href="#golf/14">14</a></div>
                <div class="golfcoursebutton"><a href="#golf/15">15</a></div>
                <div class="golfcoursebutton"><a href="#golf/16">16</a></div>
                <div class="golfcoursebutton"><a href="#golf/17">17</a></div>
                <div class="golfcoursebutton"><a href="#golf/18">18</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*EDIT* 
UPDATED WITH SOLUTION

Comment: convert it to an array `const clickOnMe = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".course-button"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've created a template part in PHP that copies a button to each slide in a carousel using fullpage.js.

Unfortunately, your code re-use is throwing an error. If we look at your source, we see:

```
div.jump-button
    button.course-button
    div.subnav-content

<script>
    const clickOnMe = ...
</script>
```

This is repeated ~20 times.

The issue is that `const` can only be declared once. After that, JS will throw an error. In fact, if we view the console, we see just that:

[image]

Basically, after the first declaration of `const clickOnMe`, an error is thrown after. That's why only the first one works. I would look into moving (and consolidating) the `<script>` where you define `clickOnMe` to the bottom and invoke that once all the HTML is loaded.

## Edit:

Regarding your comment, I see what you're referring to. You're now querying all the elements correctly by moving the event binding to the bottom (awesome!), but your event listener will need to be updated as well. The change is actually answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55071797/1253479) (by @jeyko-caicedo) by referring to the `event` object when toggling the classList.

A more complete answer would be that you need to reference the event object (to reference the clicked element) and then query the sibling `subnav-content`. One way is what jeyko suggested (via closure of the `forEach`). The other is in the event handler with either: 1 walking up the DOM tree (using `e.currentTarget.parentNode`) or 2: just reference the element directly like `e.currentTarget.nextElementSibling`.

```
let clickOnMe = document.querySelectorAll(".course-button"); 
Array.from(clickOnMe).forEach(function(el) { // updated `e` to `el`
    el.addEventListener("click", (e) => { 
        let showBox = e.currentTarget.nextElementSibling;
        showBox.classList.toggle("open-nav"); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: f-nnnn hell! How did I not think of that? You're totally right, been a long week. Thank you.

Comment: While I was really hoping that was the issue, that didn't solve it.

Comment: And it works! Thank you Jack, I owe you a virtual beer .

Comment: @rkDev - Awesome, that's great to hear!! Nice site, btw! Cheers! 

Answer (score 2):

`querySelectorAll` does not returns an array, so it doesn't have a `forEach`. Luckily, you can easily create an array out of it with `Array.from`:

```
// change this
clickOnMe.forEach(...
// to this
Array.from(clickOnMe).forEach(...
```

Comment: `querySelectorAll()` returns `NodeList` instance, which apparently [does have](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) `forEach()` method. But recently it fails all of a sudden...

Comment: Interesting, maybe it was not browser-supported when I wrote this answer. fo`NodeList#forEach` seems to work fine now in my firefox@110.0

Answer (score 2):

You're selecting the first of the document

```
document.querySelector(".subnav-content");
```

when it should be the first of the element

```
e.querySelector(".subnav-content");
```

Answer (score 1):

[querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a NodeList. It's essentially just an Array of DOM Nodes, but it doesn't support all of the Array methods that you'd expect it to have. You'll have to cast it to an array first, or manually for loop over it instead of using forEach.